# pointing at a div but it is not showing

Tags: html, css

I am working on a portfolio website, where there is a fixed sidebar which brings you to different divs also the sidebar is not mine I got from a Codepen(could this be the problem?).
the divs are displayed like so:

```
  <div id="section2">
    <img class="imgr" src="photo_3.jpg" alt="nothing">
  </div>
</main>
```

and the nav elements are displayed like this:

```
<li>
  <a href="#section2">Get In Touch</a>
</li>
```

this is an example:...?

If there is anything else I need to provide you with please tell me and thank you for any help. :)

Comment: can you place screenshot of the output you want and output you are getting?

Comment: If you have more than one of the same IDs then it will not work

Comment: Are the divs hidden, and do you want to toggle between the section divs? You need some javaScript to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and also check If you have more than one of the same IDs so try to replace with other name

```html
 <li><a href="#section">Top Image</a></li>
<li><a href="#section2">Buttom Image</a></li>
 <div id="section">
   <img class="imgr" src="https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/photoshop/using/convert-color-image-black-white/jcr_content/main-pars/before_and_after/image-before/Landscape-Color.jpg" alt="nothing">
  </div>

  <div id="section2">
          <img class="imgr" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" alt="nothing">
        </div>
```